# How to add array of unsigned short integers to XML file with base64 encoding in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, base64

I have 6 unsigned short arrays 65536 values long. Each need to be added to 6 corresponding elements in an XML file. Thus far I can successfully(I think) encode all arrays and write them to an xml file. I can then read the xml file and decode only the first 5 arrays. The 6th has issues.

Here are my encoding and decoding functions:

```
-(NSString*)encodeArrayToBase64String:(unsigned short*)ArrayofUnsignedShorts
{
    NSData *DataArray = [[NSData alloc] ArrayofUnsignedShorts length:(65536*2)];
    NSString *base64Encoded = [DataArray base64EncodedStringWithOptions:(NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength | NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed)];
    return base64Encoded;
}

-(void)decodeBase64StringToArrayData:(NSString*)encodedString
{
    //get array storage location
    unsigned short *CurrentArray = [self getCurrentArray];

    NSData *DataArray = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:encodedString options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

    void *bytes = [DataArray bytes];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [DataArray length]; i += 2) {
        unsigned short elem = OSReadLittleInt16(bytes, i);
        CurrentArray[i/2] = elem;
    }
}
```

When decoding the 6th array DataArray gets "nil" from initWithBase64EncodedString but the string has characters. I have read that this could be caused from null characters that shouldn't be in the xml file but I don't see why they would be there. This is my first time working with base64encoding in xml conversions so any other general suggestions in dealing with this are appreciated.

Comment: Look at the string and see if there is something obvious. There are few things that can be a problem, characters out of the Base64 range, incorrect length. Try a shorter `ArrayofUnsignedShorts` for the last element to try and find the sensivity. Ensure that the xml is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I might be overlooking something but I think I've solved the problem. Somewhere in the process there are string terminating characters being added to the xml file (still don't know why this is happening...) so I've added code to better handle the strings in my NSXMLParser.

Simplified code:

```
NSString *Base64EncodedString;

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    //reset string for the start of new xml element
    Base64EncodedString = @"";
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    //added characters to the total found characters of this xml element
    Base64EncodedString = [Base64EncodedString stringByAppendingString:string];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    //decoded all characters of the current xml element
    [self decodeBase64StringToArrayData:Base64EncodedString];
}
```

Previously I was calling decodeBase64StringtoArrayData in foundCharacters.